# How can I clone a git's repository subdirectory content?

Tags: git

I have been able to clone only a subdirectory of a git repository using sparse:

```
git init <repo>
cd <repo>
git remote add origin <url>
git config core.sparsecheckout true
echo "DEPLOY/*" >> .git/info/sparse-checkout
git pull --depth=1 origin master
```

Now, I would like to clone only DEPLOY directory content, not the directory itself. Does exist any way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

No, that would still be a sparsed checkout.

You would simply have to follow with a copy or a move of the `DEPLOY` content to where you need it.

Comment: Is there no way to clone only directory content? I would like to avoid moving directory's content manually.

Answer (score 0):

i also was not able to get sub-directory content.

the best for something similar problem was to jump easier into the subdir
by using a symlink later

```bash
mkdir gitFullRepo; cd gitFullRepo;
git init; 
git remote add -f origin git@gitlab.com:repo/repo.git;
git config core.sparsecheckout true; echo "subDir/" >> .git/info/sparse-checkout; 
git pull origin master;
cd ..; 

ln -s ./gitFullRepo/subDir/ ./hereIWantWork;
```